# Two Shortcodes in one page not working in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Here is my code:
When I use two shortcodes at same page only upper short code working. The second is not working.
Example: 
if I use these shortcodes `[swt_mm post_id=111] [swt_mm post_id=112]` then only `[swt_mm post_id=111]` is working and not `[swt_mm post_id=112]`

```
<?php

add_shortcode( 'swt_mm', 'swt_mm_shortcode' );
function swt_crypo_shortcode($atts = array(), $content = null, $tag ){
   shortcode_atts(array(
                        'post_type' => 'swt_mm_type',
                        'post_id'
                        ), $atts);
 /*echo $atts['post_id'];*/

  $chk=get_post_meta($atts['post_id'], 'swt_mm_type', true);

  if($chk=='table'){
    require_once dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/swt_mm_table.php';
  }else if($chk=='tooltip'){
    require_once dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/swt_mm_tooltip.php';
  }else if($chk=='box'){
    require_once dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/swt_mm_box.php';
  }else if($chk=='single-box'){
    require_once dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/swt_mm_single_box.php';
  }else{
    echo "Shortcode ID is wrong";
  }
}
```

Please help me if there are any mistakes in this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply replaced

```
require_once dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/swt_mm_single_box.php';
```

with

```
define('__ROOT__', dirname(__FILE__)); 
include __ROOT__.'/swt_mm_single_box.php';
```

and now its worked for me.
[Click Here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php)

Comment: Had the same issue. I just found out that replacing `include_once` with `include`  fixed it. 
It prevent re importing the content!